# what situations a DataGriViewCheckBox could have a dirty state?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

With datagridviewCheckox developers' talk about having "dirty states", But most of the time when a check was checked/unchecked the "Value" property changes it's value, right? If not please explain in what situations a DataGridViewCheckBox could keep a dirty state?

thanks

Comment: I guess dirty state is when the content has changed but not committed yet

Comment: Are you really talking about "dirty", or do you mean "indeterminate" state ?

Comment: good question which caused me to pop another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on CheckBox in DataGridView, it will be in dirty state. When you click on another cell or raw data will be committed and CheckBox will not be in dirty state now. You have to handle "CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged" event for your DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

When you check a Check Box in a Grid then the particular Check Box is in Dirty State and once you click on another one it loses its state.

Basically, this occurs when an edit operation is cancelled.

For more details on Dirty State and how to handle it here is a link you can check it out.

[DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you may I would like to drag this topic to another direction about dirty states of each control in a datagridview.

a datagrdiview can have a button in a cell called DateGridViewButton so the dirty state of this button is user clicks but doesn't record as clicked?

A datagridview also have comboboxes, called DataGridViewComboBox. so them the dirty state would be user selects a different item from the list but it does not record the new selection index?

thanks